# Flow 3 machines 2 manipulators

Tags: algorithm

I have 3 machines `Mach1`, `Mach2`, `Mach3` and 2 manipulators `Man1`, `Man2`

`Man1` handles `Mach1` and `Mach3`

`Man2` handles `Mach2` and `Mach3`, so there is one common Machine

each Machine has cycle time `Tmach`, each manipulator has service time `Tservice`.

Service times often differs due to some problems during servicing etc.

Machine cycle times are in most cases constant, but they are unknown at the start of system.

**The question is:**  How to optimize flow for this system? What algorithms can be used? Each reference is valuable, but the best is pseudo code.

Stupid solution for the problem is:
Start 
`Man1` handle `Mach3`, `Man2` handle `Mach2` then `Man1` handle `Mach1` and `Man2` handle `Mach3` and so on...

It is quite ok, but when handling times starts to differ, flow is not optimal.

//Edit thanks @j_random_hacker for questions that helps to specify problem more clearly

Manipulator is for example industrial robot

Cycle time means time of processing part on a machine

Service time means time in which robot handles machine it can differ due to waiting for part to be loaded, positioning part etc.

Each machine is the same, but manipulators can reach only specified machines

Jobs are qued so there are always jobs to be done
Each job is processed in one cycle
Processing can not and must not be splited

Comment: What is a manipulator?  What does "cycle time" mean?  What does "service time" mean?  Is there a set of jobs that require processing?  Can a job be processed on any machine, or only on a specific one?  How long (perhaps this means "how many cycles") does each job take to process?  Can processing of a job be split across multiple machines or not?  *Must* it be split?  Etc., etc.

Comment: Probably your question suits better at scicomp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Randomly start an idle manipulator on the machine that it can service that was serviced the longest time ago, (or randomly choose between machines if they were serviced last at the same "time").

If no manipulator is idle, wait to restart one.

This will try and even out the times spent servicing each machine.

You might want to wait in multiples of one fifth the shortest servicing time instead of using greater accuracy as this time quantisation may improve things as it allows service to complete in the same time slot a little more, which may improve things.